# Increase efficiency of creating list which is converted to pandas data frame and appended to other pandas data frame of the same length

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am creating a list which then use to make a pandas data frame then append this to another pandas data frame of the same length. The code works fine but is terribly inefficient:

```
experiment_list = []
number_of_runs = list(range(0, 10000))
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == len(df):
            break

    for j in range(len(number_of_runs)):
                   experiment_list.append(i)
```

I think the fact there is a nested for loop and a very long list creates the inefficiency.

I am using Python 3.

Is there a way to increase the efficiency of this code?

Cheers.

Comment: You can threw `if i == len(df): break` all together because it adds extra checks which are not required in your sample. Do you run this code on `Python2` or `Python3`?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Python 3

Comment: Is it possible to work with `numpy` in your case? There is an option to use [`Numpy basic array creation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html)

Comment: Cheers got it sorted. Got it as a numpy array.